# Kubernetes deploying angular frontend crash

Tags: angular, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

am trying to deploy angular frontend app on kubernetes, but i always get this error:

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
common-frontend-f74c899cc-p6tdn   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7          15m
```

when i try to see logs of pod, it print just empty line, so how can i find out where could be problem

this is dockerfile, build pipeline with this dockerfile alwys passed:

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###

# We label our stage as 'builder'
FROM node:10.11 as builder

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && npm cache clean --force
ARG NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=4096"
## Storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build
RUN npm i && mkdir /ng-app && cp -R ./node_modules ./ng-app

WORKDIR /ng-app

COPY . .

## Build the angular app in production mode and store the artifacts in dist folder
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --output-hashing=all

### STAGE 2: Setup ###

FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine

## Copy our default nginx config
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

## Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

## From 'builder' stage copy the artifacts in dist folder to default nginx public folder
COPY --from=builder /ng-app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and deployment.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: common-frontend
  labels:
    app: common-frontend
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: common-frontend
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: common-frontend
  labels:
    app: common-frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: common-frontend
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 33%
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: common-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: common-frontend
        image: skunkstechnologies/common-frontend:<VERSION>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 1
```

I really dont know what could be problem,can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Kubernetes fails liveness probe and will restart pod. Try to comment 'liveness probe' section and start it again. If it helps, correct probe parameters -- timeout, delay, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.
Your container dies and tries to restart. First of all, try to look at his logs and status:

```sh
kubectl logs <container_name>
kubectl describe pod <container_name>
```

Comment: please merge with other answer with different stages instead of two separate answers